# Getting a package contents as NSData

Tags: ios, package, nsdata, nsfilewrapper

My app creates some back-up files as Packages (in fact as directories with an extension, and an Exported UTI that conforms to com.apple.package).

I would like to be able to read them as NSData, that I can attach to an email in a MFMailComposeViewController. Actually, it doesn't work because `dataWithContentsOfURL:` returns nil when I try to read the package (I think because it's a directory, not a regular file).

I know my package files are fine because I can access them on my Mac when I download the "app container" from my iPhone.

I generate them using NSFileWrappers, and calling the `writeToURL:options:originalContentsURL:error:` method.
I don't want to use `serializedRepresentation` because it generates NSData that can be read only by NSFileWrapper (and I would like to be able to open them on my Mac, by clicking on "Show Packages Contents").

Here is the part of code that doesn't work:

```
NSURL *finalBackupURL = [outputDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"ext"];
if (![packageWrapper writeToURL:finalBackupURL options:0 originalContentsURL:nil error:error])
    @throw [NSException exceptionWithError:*error];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalBackupURL];
```

(`data = nil` whereas the file has well been created)

Thank you for your help

Comment: What about zipping that directory ?

Comment: I would have preferred avoiding this because it's time consuming (the packages may be heavy, like 50MB or more), but if I have no choice...

Comment: 50MB by mail may be heavy too, no? Your mail may be rejected by some intermediate servers because of its weight. If not, maybe a simple tar (which if I remember doesn't compress but just link them all).

Comment: In fact I want to give the choice to the user either to send it by mail, either to save it on iCloud Drive. But it seems to be the same issue when trying to save a package on iCloud Drive. So I definitively have to transform my packages to regular files.. :(